# How to hide php values inside a div at different CSS media

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following
**page.php**

```
<div class="width_mobil"><?php $max_columns =2; ?></div>
         <div class="width_ipad"><?php $max_columns = 3; ?></div>
          <div class="width_desktop"><?php $max_columns = 4; ?></div>
```

CSS
**style.css**

```
    .width_mobil{display: block;visibility: visible}
    .width_ipad{display: none !important;visibility: hidden;}
    .width_desktop{display: none !important;visibility: hidden}
   
 @media only screen and (min-width:481px){
    .width_mobil{display: none !important;visibility: hidden}
    .width_ipad{display: block;visibility: visible;}
    .width_desktop{display: none !important;visibility: hidden} }
  
  @media only screen and (min-width:981px){
    .width_mobil{display: none !important;;visibility: hidden}
    .width_ipad{display: none !important;;visibility: hidden}
    .width_desktop{display: block;visibility: visible;}}
```

But when I load the page on a screen width=375(Mobil) and echo out $max_columns it displays 4 instead of 2.
When moving the divs in a different order it just displays the last value of the last seen div e.g

```
<div class="width_desktop"><?php $max_columns = 4; ?></div>
<div class="width_mobil"><?php $max_columns =2; ?></div>
             <div class="width_ipad"><?php $max_columns = 3; ?></div>
```

I get 3 when echo $max_columns
I want just the div content on the right screen width so when on a mobil I want $max_column =2
on a desktop $max_columns = 4 and on an ipad $max_column =3

Any help welcome

Comment: IMO this has nothing to do with php. It is about how to order html elements via css.

Comment: @B001ᛦ I want to remove the php inside the div using css at different media that is why I put the php tag on, I sorry if that was not correct

Comment: _I want to remove the php inside the div..._ It is not php. It is html what you want to remove.

Comment: @B001ᛦ ok then, is there a way to do that? if you know I would be greatfull if you won't mind sharing

Comment: Title is total misleading. PHP does not hide anything. You only see what is printed out.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I want to hide the php inside the div because if you put an image in the it will not show in different media but for dome reason the php shows from the last div. That is why I thought it was important to put it in the title cause hidding a div I can do but forsoem reason the php contents still keeps. If you know how to get the right php value for $max_columns at the different media i would be very gratefull

Comment: What you are doing is totally nonsense, because each line of PHP code will be executed. So at the end $max_columns is always 3 (referring to the first codeblock). If you want to tell PHP how many columns should be generated, you will need to do some AJAX work.

Answer (score 1):

by assuming you want this, you can try like below

```
<?php
 if($max_columns == 2){
     $max_columns = '2';
     $class = 'width_mobil';
 }
 if($max_columns == 3){
     $max_columns = '3';
     $class = 'width_ipad';
 }
 if($max_columns == 4){
     $max_columns = '4';
     $class = 'width_desktop';
 }
?>


 <div class="<?php echo $class:?>"> <?php echo $max_columns:?></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I want to set the columns on the different media this way I still need to determine what I want the $max_columns to be, that is why I thought that when displaying the div at the different media might get me the right $max_columns value